# Strings with whitespace in a list?

Tags: c++, string, list, whitespace

I have this function sentanceParse with a string input which returns a list. The input might be something like "Hello my name is Anton. What's your name?" and then the return value would be a list containing "Hello my name is Anton" and "What's your name?". However, this is not what happens. It seems as if the whitespaces in the sentences are treated like a separator and therefore the return is rather "Hello", "my", "name" etc instead of what I expected.

How would you propose I solve this?

As I am not a 100% sure the problem does not lie within my code, I will add that to the post as well:

Main:

```
list<string> mylist = sentanceParse(textCipher);
list<string>::iterator it;
for(it = mylist.begin(); it != mylist.end(); it++){
    textCipher = *it;
    cout << textCipher << endl; //This prints out the words separately instead of the entire sentances.
```

sentanceParse:

```
list<string> sentanceParse(string strParse){
    list<string> strList;
    int len = strParse.length();
    int pos = 0;
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
        if(strParse.at(i) == '.' || strParse.at(i) == '!' || strParse.at(i) == '?'){
            if(i < strParse.length() - 1){
                while(i < strParse.length() - 1 && (strParse.at(i+1) == '.' || strParse.at(i+1) == '!' || strParse.at(i+1) == '?')){
                    if(strParse.at(i+1) == '?'){
                        strParse.replace(i, 1, "?");
                    }
                    strParse.erase(i+1, 1);
                    len -= 1;
                }
            }
            char strTemp[2000];
            int lenTemp = strParse.copy(strTemp, i - pos + 1, pos);
            strTemp[lenTemp] = '\0';
            std::string strAdd(strTemp);
            strList.push_back(strAdd);
            pos = i + 1;
            count ++;
        }
    }

    if(count == 0){
        strList.push_back(strParse);
    }

    return strList;
}
```

Comment: Any reason you're not using Boost here? There's [`boost::tokenizer`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/tokenizer/index.html) for example, which will do your job perfectly fine (though the documentation is a little bit.. Spartan).

Comment: Never heard of it before actually, I'll check it out.

Comment: Basically, it will look something like `tokenizer<char_seperator<char>> toks(strParse, char_seperator<char>(".!?")); for(auto& tok : toks){ /* process each sentence... */ }`

Comment: I'm downloading it now to try some implementations. I'm thinking about one thing though. Will the ., !, and ? be included in the returned strings? And if an input string would look like "HI!!!!", what would the return be?

Comment: @Xeo Using boost for something so simple would be a bit overkill.

Comment: If it works, I suppose I could always copy only the files required for this script to my project.

Comment: @RTS: *What?* So you'd rather reinvent the wheel than take a finished and tested solution? What always with this "Boost is overkill for small things", that's seriously annoying me. Boost was *made* to solve small problems aswell as large ones. It's just a collection of libraries. Just because you use one part of Boost doesn't mean that the whole collection gets involved. And a good C++ programmer should have a Boost installation already anyways.

Comment: @Anton: Read the documentation, the `char_seperator` constructor takes 3 arguments - dropped delimiters, kept delimiters, and how empty tokens behave (drop or keep). I just noticed that the kept delimiters (what you seem to want) would be a single token each, so you might have to supply your own seperator.

Comment: `char strTemp[2000];` is a security time bomb.

Comment: @Xeo A good C++ programmer would be able to write a lexer this simple faster than you could read the documentation for boost tokenizer. Also boost brings a huge dependency into your program with a complicated build system. On top of that it proliferates everywhere and contrary to popular belief, is not that modular. I have never successfully used only a single module of boost as they all tend to include each other. Now don't get me wrong, Boost is one of the best libraries ever written. However the use of a >100MB library to save 5 lines of code is the definition of overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation of sentence parse is wrong, here is a simpler correct solution.

```
std::list<std::string> sentence_parse(const std::string &str){
    std::string temp;
    std::list<std::string> t;

    for(int x=0; x<str.size();++x){
       if(str[x]=='.'||str[x]=='!'||str[x]=='?'){
           if(temp!="")t.push_back(temp);//Handle special case of input with
                                         //multiple punctuation Ex. Hi!!!!
           temp="";
       }else temp+=str[x];
    }
    return t;
}
```

EDIT:

Here is a full example program using this function. Type some sentences in your console, press enter and it will spit the sentences out with a newline separating them instead of punctuation.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <list>
std::list<std::string> sentence_parse(const std::string &str){
    std::string temp;
    std::list<std::string> t;

    for(int x=0; x<str.size();++x){
        if(str[x]=='.'||str[x]=='!'||str[x]=='?'){
            if(temp!="")t.push_back(temp);//Handle special case of input with
                                          //multiple punctuation Ex. Hi!!!!
            temp="";
        }else temp+=str[x];
    }
    return t;
}
int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    std::string s;

    while (std::getline(std::cin,s)) {       
        std::list<std::string> t= sentence_parse(s);
        std::list<std::string>::iterator x=t.begin();
        while (x!=t.end()) {
             std::cout<<*x<<"\n";
            ++x;
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But say the input was "One two three!", would they not be divided as "One", "two" and "three" in the list? My problem is the whitespaces acting like separators.

Comment: Try this code it will work and will not have the whitespace act as separators.

Comment: It does not work (tested it). It returns only the last words from each given sentance. When a sentance is added to the list, only the content after the last whitespace is included.

Comment: I just compiled this code on my own computer and tested it, and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
// This function should be easy to adapt to any basic libary
// this is in Windows MFC
// pass in a string, a char and a stringarray
// returns an array of strings using char as the separator

void tokenizeString(CString theString, TCHAR theToken, CStringArray *theParameters)
{
    CString temp = "";
    int i = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < theString.GetLength(); i++ ) 
    {                                   
        if (theString.GetAt(i) != theToken) 
        {
            temp += theString.GetAt(i); 
        }
        else
        {
            theParameters->Add(temp);   
            temp = "";
        }
        if(i == theString.GetLength()-1)
            theParameters->Add(temp);
    }
}
```

Comment: This would work if the input wasn't user generated. Let's say the input is "Hi!!! I am Anton. What's your name!?". In this case, I would like the return to be "Hi!", "I am Anton.", "What's your name?". I'll probably think about working with an array the way you do here instead of a list though.